# memory assignment for a structure with constant member

Tags: c, variables, embedded, system, structure

I'm programming embedded system with C language and I define a structure with two constant member "val" and "ptr".

```
typedef struct{
const u8 val;
u8 *const ptr;
}TEST;
```

If I declare such type variable as a global, would the variable be placed in ROM or in RAM?

```
TEST var;
```

Thanks

Comment: Why should it be stored in ROM. Memory is allocated either in stack or heap!!! Please mention the language you are using as memory allocation varies from language to language.

Comment: I'm programming embedded system with c language, and I know all the variables will be placed either in RAM,if declare "u8 var", or in ROM, if declare "const u8 var".

But I'm not sure whether a structure with constant members will place its member in the RAM or ROM,  when I declare a global structure variable as I mentioned above.  Thank you.

Comment: Please add proper tag to the question so that proper people can guide you.

Comment: It will depend on your system — read the manual.  You will not be able to modify `TEST.ptr` once the variable is initialized, so it will always be a null pointer (since you didn't provide any explicit initialization, it is all zeroes).  This is probably not what you had in mind.  The variable should not be in ROM; the `TEST.val` may be modified at runtime.  Your compiler may have other ideas...

Comment: Since you have to rely on the fact that a complete instance of your struct is accessible with a single pointer your const members at least have to be accessible in the same memory area as the const members. For this I assume the memory manager (if there is one) is not smart enough to ensure the right access addresses if one member is in ROM and another is in RAM.

Comment: You can test this on your particular system if you cast the member to a not-const-type and try to modify it: `(u8)(var.val) = 13;`. Of course you *should* not use this in productive code. If the assignment fails the value propably was in ROM, if it worked the const is only a compile-time tag.

Comment: I did some test and found that if I declare `const TEST var;`, the value "val" and address "ptr" cannot be modified. But if without `const` description before the declaration:`TEST var;`, all member can change its value, even though the structure member was initially set `const` type.
So I think whether the variable is in ROM or RAM depend on `const` description when declaring the `TEST` type structure variable.

Answer (score 2):

The TEST instance needs to go into read/write memory - the TEST instance is non-const, even though all of it's members are const.  GCC will emit the struct into .data which is read/write and the linker script should put this into the appropriate memory type.

'const' in C doesn't guarantee that the storage really is immutable - it only means that a program that performs strictly to the C standard won't have a 'const' item modified.

If you want data to go into ROM then you'll need an appropriate linker script that puts .rodata sections into ROM.

Comment: I would add two things to this decent answer. One is that within the source you will need to use compiler specific keywords (such as "attribute section" with gcc) to make the variables go in the appropriate sections defined in the linker script, the other is that maybe the role of "const" should be clarified a bit. For example typically you may pass pointers to const to functions which are supposed to not modify the contents, and the "const volatile" apparent oxymoron may also worth a mention.